# How to show and modifications icons in swipe-angular-list using angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, swipe, swiper.js

I have installed this [plugin](https://github.com/leifermendez/swipe-angular-list) in Angular version 8. I have followed step by step it, but I have a problem, Icons, edit and trash doesn't show in view.

I have this code:

```
<div>
     <div>
          <sw-item-list *ngFor="let item of data" [inside]="item"
                [item-class]="'list-custom'" [show-mark]="false" [disable-mark]="item?.disable"
                [editTemplate]="editTemplate" [trashTemplate]="trashTemplate" [markTemplate]="defaultMark"
                [customTemplate]="customTemplateSrc" [notMarkTemplate]="defaultNotMark" (callback)="action($event)">
          </sw-item-list>
     </div>
 </div>
          <ng-template #editTemplate>
            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #trashTemplate>
            <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #defaultMark>
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          </ng-template>
         <ng-template #defaultNotMark>
            <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #customTemplateSrc let-item='item' let-id='id'>

            <div
              style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;  align-items: center;   box-sizing: border-box;   padding: 0 35px;    position: relative;   height: inherit;">
              <div>
                <h3 style="margin-top: 0;margin-bottom: 0;">{{ item.PersonId}}</h3>
                <small style="color:gray;font-weight:500;">{{ item.Department}}</small>
              </div>
            </div>
      </ng-template>
```

Also, please how to edit it, I want to show only one button in icons (ex. Add new Item).

Can you share with me any idea if you have used this plugin?